# Karma output duplicating test results

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When running tests karma seems to be duplicating the last test multiple times, the amount of times the test is duplicated seems to depend on the number of tests and the browsers that are used for the run.

If just using one browser (PhantomJS or Chrome) for one test, the test is shown twice, when using both browsers the same single test is shown up to 6 times.

I've added logging into the test, the log occurs the once per test per browser, so presumably the tests are running the correct number of times but just duplicating the results shown.

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '_test/test.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

test.js

```
describe('karma testing', function () {
    it('tests karma is working', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        console.log('test1');
    });
});
```

Output 1 Browser (Chrome)

```
07 10 2015 16:41:14.890:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
07 10 2015 16:41:14.897:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
07 10 2015 16:41:16.364:INFO [Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 0uvPocfSI0prGxwdAAAA with id 29520633
LOG: 'test1'
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.003 secs
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.011 secs / 0.003 secs)
```

Output 2 Browsers (PhantomJS, Chrome)

```
07 10 2015 16:27:31.399:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
07 10 2015 16:27:31.407:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
07 10 2015 16:27:31.420:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
07 10 2015 16:27:32.886:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket P5focoe7004aPX1rAAAA with id 49258591
07 10 2015 16:27:33.077:INFO [Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket BGtRdqevRGGXZTA-AAAB with id 42323971
LOG: 'test1'
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.003 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.007 secs / 0.003 s
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.007 secs / 0.003 s
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0) LOG: 'test1'
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.007 secs / 0.003 s
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.007 secs / 0.003 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.007 secs / 0.003 secs)
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.028 secs / 0.002 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

I have tested this with and without karma-cli installed and the results are the same.

I have looked around stack overflow and google and a few people seem to have encountered similar issues but there are no meaningful answers.

Comment: Any luck figuring this one out?  We're having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've just been living with it for now, are you running the same config?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues when trying to get a prettifier working.

karma.conf takes several options, like autoWatch, browsers, singleRun - right? Among all these is a property called client.

The client property is an object with a few properties of its own. Its purpose is to configure settings relevant to the testing client, like Chrome, for example.

client has a property called captureConsole. This defaults to true, which means any console logging in the browser is sent back to your bash, too. So, with that turned on by default, I was seeing both Chrome's console logging and the prettified tap output.

Try this setting in yours and see if it helps!

```
client: {
    captureConsole: false
},
```